# Relation between the transpose and adjoint of a linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, adjoint-operators

This question is **not** about matrices.

Kunze, Linear algebra (1971) defines **transpose of a linear transformation** and **adjoint of a linear transformation**.

Kunze states the relation between the adjoint of $T$ and the transpose **of the matrix of $T$**, but I could not find the relation between the adjoint of $T$ and the transpose of $T$ **as a linear transformation**.

> **Transpose**: [image]
>
> **Adjoint**: [image]

What is the relation between these two definitions? Note again, I am **not** asking about the relation between the adjoint of $T$ and the transpose of the matrix of $T$, so questions like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2362774/relationship-between-definition-of-adjoint-of-a-linear-operator-and-the-transpos) are not duplicates.

Comment: you can check it https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3456174/565609

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\textsf V$ and $\textsf W$ be vector spaces over $F$ with the inner products $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle_1$ and $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle_2$, respectively.

For $v\in\textsf V$, define the **linear** map $\varphi_1(v) : \textsf V \to F$ by $\varphi_1(v)(u) = \langle u,v \rangle_1$.

It is easy to see that $\varphi_1$ is an injective linear transformation between $\textsf V$ and $\textsf V^*$. Also, since $\textsf V$ and $\textsf V^*$ has the same dimension, $\varphi_1$ is an **isomorphism**.

Then, we can *identify* $\textsf V$ with $\textsf V^*$ through $\varphi_1$. The same happens between $\textsf W$ and $\textsf W^*$ with the isomorphism $\varphi_2 : \textsf W \to \textsf W^*$ defined in a similar way.

Now, this maps will help us to identify $\textsf T^*$ with $\textsf T^t$. More precisely, we have the following relationship:

$$\varphi_1 \circ \textsf T^* = \textsf T^t \circ \varphi_2.$$

*Note* : Here, $\textsf T^*$ is the **unique** linear transformation, from $\textsf W$ to $\textsf V$, such that

$$\langle \textsf T(x), y \rangle_2 = \langle x,\textsf T^*(y) \rangle_1$$

for all $x\in\textsf V$ and $y\in\textsf W$.

Comment: Thanks! great answer. Is there a name for $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$? Also, is it common to call $T^t$ the "dual" of $T$, and $T^*$ the "adjoint"? (I just want standard terminology to distinguish them, and distinguish them from the transpose matrix).

Comment: Thanks. Well, I don't know any specific name for those functions, they could be said to be the *natural isomorphisms*, since it does not depend on the choice of a basis. Also, it is very common to say that $\textsf T^t$ and $\textsf T^*$ are the *dual* and the *adjoint* of $\textsf T$, respectively. I'm glad that my answer helped you to clarify the things.

Answer (score 0):

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional inner product space. 
Then every linear map $f:V\to F$ can be written as $f(x)=\langle y, x\rangle$ for a unique $y\in V$, so *under this correspondence* the transpose of a linear map $T:V\to W$ is taken to the adjoint of $T$.